# Classificador SVM de imagens não funciona

Tags: python, algoritmo, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, inteligência-artificial

Olá, eu estou com um programa em Python que utiliza a biblioteca Dlib 19.10, o classificador utiliza um arquivo xml para fazer o aprendizado das imagens e depois eu executo o seguinte código que cria um arquivo .svm para a classificação:

```
import dlib

opcoes = dlib.simple_object_detector_training_options()
opcoes.add_left_right_image_flips = True
opcoes.C = 5

dlib.train_simple_object_detector("recursos/treinamento_casas.xml", "recursos/detector_casas.svm",opcoes)
```

O primeiro problema acontece na linha 4 (`opcoes.add_left_right_image_flips = True`), quando é colocado `False` não há erro algum, o treinamento ocorre normalmente, porém quando eu coloco `True` aparece o seguinte erro:

---

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/marco/Desktop/Projeto_de_pesquisa/treinamento_casas.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       dlib.train_simple_object_detector("recursos/treinamento_casas.xml",
>   "recursos/detector_casas.svm",opcoes) RuntimeError: An impossible set
>   of object labels was detected. This is happening because none of the
>   object locations checked by the supplied image scanner is a close
>   enough match to one of the truth boxes in your training dataset. To
>   resolve this you  need to either lower the match_eps, adjust the
>   settings of the image scanner so that it is capable of hitting this
>   truth box, or adjust the offending truth  rectangle so it can be
>   matched by the current image scanner. Also, if you are  using the
>   scan_fhog_pyramid object then you could try using a finer image 
>   pyramid. Additionally, the scan_fhog_pyramid scans a fixed aspect
>   ratio box  across the image when it searches for objects. So if you
>   are getting this error and you are using the scan_fhog_pyramid, it's
>   very likely the problem is that  your training dataset contains truth
>   rectangles of widely varying aspect  ratios. The solution is to make
>   sure your training boxes all have about the  same aspect ratio.
>
> image index              23  match_eps:               0.5  best
>   possible match:     0.496824 truth rect:              [(508, 482)
>   (600, 650)] truth rect width/height: 0.550296 truth rect area:
>   15717 nearest detection template rect:              [(492, 515) (595,
>   618)] nearest detection template rect width/height: 1 nearest
>   detection template rect area:         10816

O segundo problema ocorre na detecção dos objetos nas imagens, o algoritmo não reconhece nenhum objeto nas imagens de teste, inclusive nem mesmo as imagens que foram utilizadas para o treinamento, o algoritmo deveria desenhar um retângulo nos objetos detectados e isso não ocorre. Trecho de código:

```
contador = 0
detectorCasa = dlib.simple_object_detector("recursos/detector_casas.svm")
for imagem in glob.glob(os.path.join("imagens/teste", "*.jpg")):
    img = cv2.imread(imagem)
    objetosDetectados = detectorCasa(img)
    for d in objetosDetectados:
        e, t, d, b = (int(d.left()), int(d.top()), int(d.right()), int(d.bottom()))
        cv2.rectangle(img, (e,t), (d, b), (0,0,255), 2)
        contador += 1

    cv2.imshow("Detector de casas", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

O erro seria no arquivo xml?